# bufferToggle when active ajax request

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to implement a buffer so I can combine events while an ajax request is in-flight so they can essentially be batched together and sent when as ajax request is not in-flight. For example, if I have something like this:

```
const updateQueue$ = new Subject<ISettings>();

// nothing in flight right now so this should go straight to the server
updateQueue$.next({ volume: 30 });

// previous update is still in flight so queue this up
updateQueue$.next({ volume: 40 });
updateQueue$.next({ volume: 50 });
updateQueue$.next({ volume: 60, muted: true });

// original update finally finishes, combine all the latest 
// items and send them now which should look something like
// this: { volume: 60, muted: true }
```

I have a stackblitz for this, but it's not quite working as I want and I'm not sure why
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vgd9mq

```
const allowSend$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
const updateQueue$ = new Subject<ISettings>();

updateQueue$
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(
    tap(item => log("item added to updateQueue$", item)),

    // It seems to me I have *something* wrong here, but I haven't been able to pin point it. This doesn't appear to ever run.
    bufferToggle(
      allowSend$.asObservable().pipe(filter(allowSend => !allowSend)),
      () =>
        allowSend$.asObservable().pipe(
          filter(allowSend => allowSend),
          tap(() => "closing buffer")
        )
    ),

    tap(bufferContents =>
      console.log("bufferContents pre filter", bufferContents)
    ),

    filter(buffer => !!buffer.length),

    map(bufferContents => {
      return Object.assign({}, ...bufferContents);
    }),

    tap(bufferContents => console.log("combined buffer", bufferContents)),

    // Send network request
    switchMap(value => {
      allowSend$.next(false);
      return sendToServer(value as any);
    }),

    tap(() => allowSend$.next(true))

    // Push to subject to allow next debounced value through
    // tap(() => allowNext$.next(true))
  )
  .subscribe(response => {
    log("done sending to server");
  });

interval(2000)
  .pipe(
    map(() => {
      updateQueue$.next(generateRandomEvent());
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [`throttle`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttle) to drop emissions until a specified observable emits.  There are two settings to control emission behavior:

- `leading` - allows the first emission to get through.
- `trailing` - allows the last emission to get through (*the last one before the "specified observable" emitted*).

The idea is to use `throttle` to drop emissions, then after the http call completes, call `.next` on the trigger observable so throttle will resume allowing emissions.

We can use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to accumulate all emissions into a single change object.

So in simplified form, this should work for you:

```js
  resume$ = new Subject<void>();  // used to tell 'throttle' to allow emissions
  queue$ = new Subject<number>();

  work$ = this.queue$.pipe(
    // accumulate all updates into a single update object
    scan((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, ...cur }), {}),
    throttle(() => this.resume$, { leading: true, trailing: true }),
    concatMap(state => this.updateState(state).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.resume$.next())
    ))
  );
```

Since `throttle` is controlling emissions, I think only 1 emission at a time will ever make it through, so I don't think there will be any difference in behavior, whether you choose `switchMap`, `concatMap`, `mergeMap` or `exhaustMap`.

Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66534814-simple?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example.

Here I updated your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66534814?file=index.ts) :-)

Comment: So this would work if I didn't need to merge the results. some of these "settings" may not have everything. I updated your stackblitz's "generateRandomEvent" fn here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66534814-vkqrb2?file=index.ts. That's why I was thinking I needed to use buffer rather than throttle or concatmap or something. I could just send *all* the settings with every update and throttle that, but I'm trying to avoid that if I can.

Comment: easy fix.  We can just add a `scan` in there to combine all emissions into a single object.  It will potentially send redundant fields, but I think it might be the least complex solution.  I updated the SB.

Comment: I seriously appreciate the help. Just out of curiosity though, is there a reason to *not* use one of the buffer operators? It seems like this would be the case they were designed for.

Comment: honestly, I'm not familiar with the buffer operators and this just seems simpler to me (*possibly because I'm not familiar with the buffer operators* !) :-)